# Dot notation in C?

Tags: c, oop

Is it possible to implement dot notation in C (OOP) a la Python?

Something like:

```
struct myClass {
    ...
    ...
}
```

And then have a method on that struct like:

```
myClass.someMethod();
```

Comment: Do you mean a [static member](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm)? Dot notation is for instances of a class/struct.

Comment: A struct with pointers to functions?

Comment: Well just methods attached to structs, which I assume are the closest you can get to classes in C

Comment: @Jasonca1 Luke is asking whether you really meant `myClass.someMethod();` or rather `myClass myInstance; myInstance.someMethod();`.

Comment: you can somewhat kludge it (e.g. instance specific methods, which can be done in C *kinda*) you are responsible for passing on the value of the the member back to the functions.

Comment: I believe that's what C++ is for :)

Comment: You can use function pointers but often it is better to use specially named (prefixed) functions and treat/document those as if they were member functions.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Nah, C++ is for creating a poodle out of a feather, when all you wanted was to avoid creating a hen out of a feather.

Comment: @sepp2k Both. Being able to implement static methods and member methods.

Comment: @Jasonca1 `typename.id` is not valid syntax in C, nor is `typename::id` (which is how you'd access static members in C++), so no, there's no way to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `someMethod()` will be a function pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    void (*someMethod) (void);

}Test;

void asd (void)
{
    printf("works");
}

int main(void)
{
    Test test;
    test.someMethod = asd;
    test.someMethod(); // will print works
}
```

Comment: That only works if you remove the `typedef` (making `Test` a variable instead of a type name).

Comment: But not the function will not have a pointer back to the struct holding it!

Comment: your code won't compile. Also `typedef` is a bad idea!

Comment: @Ahmed Masud this is pesudo code, but ill change it if its so big problem

Comment: If so, please add language to indicate.